# Logging to sepecific event source using NLog

Tags: .net, logging, nlog

I can able to log windows event source using NLog.

But what i want is to write a specific event source: such as : MyEventSource

My config is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <targets>

    <target name="eventlog" xsi:type="EventLog"  log="MyEventSource" />

  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="eventlog" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

**Well when i try to log anthing, MyEventSource is created but log message is written to general windows [7] applicantion event source not MyEventSource.**

**Update:**

```
<target name="eventlog" xsi:type="EventLog"  
layout="${message}" log="custom_log" source="custom_source" />
```

Make no difference

Answer (score -1):

You should set target's source and log like this:

```
<target xsi:type="EventLog" 
   name="eventlog" 
   layout="${message}"
   source="custom_source" 
   log="custom_log"/>
```

Comment: In this case you should use the source attribute, not the log: <target name="eventlog" xsi:type="EventLog" source="MyEventSource" /> If it doesn't work, try to change source name - nlog will configure it for Application log.

Comment: What you mean by "use"? just config file...If i not set log ,it will not create  a custom event source called custom_log...

Comment: <target name="eventlog" xsi:type="EventLog" source="MyEventSource" /> does not work either

Comment: Great! :) Now change the MyEventSource to MyEventSource2: <target name="eventlog" xsi:type="EventLog" source="MyEventSource2" />

Comment: I do it...I am even at MyEventSource10...Does not work practically...In theory it has no "logic"-meaningless...why you think this will work? it does not even create custom event source event

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to run

> InstallNLogConfig.exe c:\path\to\NLog.config

As described in [Deploying NLog configuration files](http://nlog-project.org/2010/09/25/deploying-nlog-configuration.html) ?

InstallNLogConfig.exe is now [included in the latest NuGet package.](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/commit/43f48289ad1f658d52cf6db3338a9e74bc8e6d02)

Comment: Apologies - link works today - must have been a problem on the nlog-project.com server yesterday...